# Phonegap platform add android set target

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I can't believe the amount of time I've been wasting on this. Something that is so important you expect it could be done in no-time turns out to be a huge and frustrating task.

Why is it that I cannot set my desired android target when I use the command "phonegap platform add android". It automaticly uses target 22 but I want to use target 10. I do not have target 22 installed but I do have target 10 installed. So why is it that I cannot use it?

I searched all over the web. Tried all kinds of solutions but no results. Here is what I tried:

- I have set all required environment variables like ANDROID_SDK, ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS (unless I'm forgetting something please let me know)
- I installed ant
- I changed the AndroidManifest.xml file
- I changed the project.properties file
- I tried phonegap platform add android@2.3.3
- I changed the config.xml file by setting the value of android-minSdkVersion to 10

And here is some other info that might give you an idea about my system:

- I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- I'm using phonegap 5.3.6
- The android command works
- ant -version returns Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
- jdk works because I develop games in Java
- jdk version is 1.8
- git --version returns git version 1.9.1

I saw a lot of topics involving target 19 and 18 and such although the current phonegap version uses target 22. I have an older phone which runs android 2.3.6 (hence the target 10, android version 2.3.3).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@TheBoneJarmer,
 simple problem, target 10 is not supported with 5.x. Per the [phongap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) for 4.0,

> *As a general rule, platforms are deprecated as they dip below 5% on Google's [distribution dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html).*

For [Cordova 5.1.1](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/index.html), which is not Phonegap, but is a 5.X varient, it reads:

> *Cordova supports Android 4.0.x (starting with Android API level 14) and higher. As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by Cordova as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution dashboard. Android versions earlier than API level 10, and the 3.x versions (Honeycomb, API levels 11-13) fall significantly below that 5% threshold.*

The solution is to start over and set your phonegap compiler to 3.x or 4.x

Which could be `phonegap platform add android@3.7.0`

NOTE: The version number is NOT the Android version, but the "phonegap" version for the compiler.

A few more notes. This last week Cordova moved all the plugins to the new server without warning, announcement or tweet. Many of us that answer forum questions were caught by surprise. This mean MUCH of the online documentation from Cordova went down. There is current documentation (not redirected), but it ignores the older version.

The new documentation is here:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/overview/

You can find more details at:
[Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)
Read **6. Not setting the "phonegap version" for your compiler**